# shellapi error when building Google Test

Tags: visual-studio-2005, shellexecute, googletest

I downloaded Google Test.
Then i opened "**gtest.sln**" file.
After conversion i clicked "build" but Visual Studio 2005 gave the errors below repeatedly.
What should i do?
Thank you

```
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\shellapi.h(69) : error C2065: 'WHWND' : undeclared identifier
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\shellapi.h(69) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hwnd'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\shellapi.h(69) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\shellapi.h(69) : error C2491: 'ShellExecute' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\shellapi.h(69) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the order of include directories.

It seems to be you have PlatformSDK first in the include path; try to move it "down" so that VS include directories will be used first. It's probably that gtest is not compatible with your version of PlatformSDK.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very very much :))))) This really helped me very much. I couldn't solve this issue for days :))